# What is pctincrease in oracle?how the memory is allocated,resized,and autoextended while creating a table space

Tags: sql, database, database-design, oracle9i

How the memory is allocated,reallocated and autoextended while creating tablespaces?what is meant by initial and default in tablespaces and how the next is a multiple of five times DB_BLOCK_SIZE?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't really understand your questions, but your best bet is probably to study the [Oracle 9i Database Concepts](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B10501_01/server.920/a96524/toc.htm) manual.